# how to send some message to the users when now is looking my site's web page

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, html

how to send this messages to many people who looking my site on google app engine

1.using html5 ?

2.using ajax  ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some technologies you can use for this include COMET (Ajax Push), Hidden IFrame (basically make the page never terminate and just send more data as it becomes available so the socket is never closed), html5 and websockets, or plain old fashioned XmlHttpRequest (some sort of polling mechanism as described by mirthlab).

Comment: The Channel API is scheduled for release in 1.4. It should help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an ajax poller to poll the server for the message and then display it.

Your question is a little unclear though. What will the message be used for. Does it have to show up without the user refreshing the page? Etc.